# Razor Control's Width from Model

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

Morning SO,

I've been scratching my head over this for a few days - but had limited trials at getting it to work; I am trying to dynamically assign a value to a TEXTBOXFOR control's Width.

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Title, new { @Style = string.Format("width:{0}px;", Model.Items[i].Width), @ReadOnly = "true" })

<label style="width:@Model.Items[i].Width px; padding-top:8px;">@Model.Items[i].Title</label>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Title, new { @Style = "width:" + Model.Items[i].Width + "px;", @ReadOnly = "true" })
```

I have tried a few other examples - but nothing seems to actually work.

Does anybody have a correct format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a codeblock inside a code block is valid in razor.

Try it without the `@` before Style and ReadOnly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Title, new { style = String.Format("width:{0}px;", Model.Items[i].Width), ReadOnly = "true" })
```

to reproduce this, I have this inside my Index method:

```
var model = new List<string>() { "100", "200" };
return View(model);
```

and in my view:

```
@foreach (string s in Model)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => s, new { style = String.Format("width:{0}px;", s)} )<br/>
}
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Serv, but both ways work...
I had mistyped my @model definition - it had a capitol 'M' instead of lowercase. <facepalm> <double-facepalm>

Comment: Good to know. Just to be sure, I've explained the procedure to rebuild this.